# Wireless Networking: WDS Bridge vs AP/Client Bridge

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

Everything I've read/seen so far leads me to believe that the answer to this question is that these are just two different means to the same end. However, just to be 100% clear, I'm going to ask anyway.

When it comes to wireless bridge networking, what are the differences (advantages/drawbacks) to a WDS bridge model vs a Access Point -> Client bridge model?

I know how to configure each model, but for the longest time I've been doing the AP/Client model of configuring the source side as an Access Point and the receive side as a wireless client. This makes it simple for me in the case of adding or replacing a client antenna as I can simply program in the AP SSID and password and send it to the customer to hookup and for them it "just works". Is  there a drawback to doing it this way (other than having an SSID exposed unless hidden)?

As for WDS, are there any drawbacks there that would give an AP/Client Bridge an advantage? My line of work generally consists of getting Internet from point A to point B (and sometimes to point C and D too). I just want to make sure I'm operating in the most efficient way possible.